# What does one use to make formatted documents (such as articles, papers, slides, etc) without Office & such?

Tags: microsoft-word, vim, documents, markup

As a VIM user, I'm so happy not to have to use the mouse for my programming works. I don't know much about markup languages, though, so I still have to use Office and other mouse-based software to create documents. What are the options available that go well with VIM?

Comment: TeX (and LaTeX)! But this question is out of scope on this site, I think.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Because it sounds like software recommendation, and is mostly opinion based I think.

Comment: But I'm not asking for specific software, I'm asking for the kind of software I need, ie, "What do I use to access sites? A: browsers" instead of "What is the best browser out there?"

Answer (score 2):

### [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

LaTeX would definitely be your best bet.

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/214543/261896) also has a couple of good links.

Comment: What's great is that there's in an entire StackExchange site dedicated to LaTeX! [TeX.SE]

Comment: @MichaelFrank you should be working for them - ;-)

Comment: Not if you saw how many times I had to edit that comment to get the mark up to work. D:

Comment: Know exactly what you mean.