# How to convert a document in some form of mark-up to a formatted Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

My team has to produce a large number of reports in the coming months and these reports have to be to a very specific Word template with defined heading styles, bullet styles etc. Ideally I want my team to be focussing on the content of the document and not having to worry about the exact formatting or whether they are setting up a table correctly. On this basis what I would like to achieve is to have some way of taking a document produced in some type of simple Mark-up style language and then taking that text and putting it in the stanrd Word template with correct formatting etc. Is there any easy way to acheive this?

Comment: The question is too vague. What is "the standard Word template"? One you create? What is "correct formatting"?

Comment: A related question is http://superuser.com/questions/209897/text-formatter-tools/

Comment: The standard word template is one they have created. Nothing special just certain formatting for headings, certain formatting for tables etc. Correct formatting would be making sure top level headings have Heading 1 formatting, tables are formatted in the standard way etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) for the simple mark-up language. (Which is what Superuser uses, by the way.) There are a variety of ways of converting that to other formats, such as things Word can handle, like RTF or HTML, using, e.g., [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). But how easy it would be to script getting it into a specific Word template would depend on the template, and may require using Word's built in Visual Basic scripting. Personally, I'd tell whoever is insisting on Word that it probably isn't the best format in this case, and stick with some other format that is easier to script consistently, based on plain text which can be manipulated in all sorts of ways, such as HTML or LaTeX.

Comment: Word documents are just the industry standard so I doubt that they would accept anything different. We are usually asked to issue word documents as well as, for example, PDFs.

Comment: It's OK if Word is the final desired format; it's just that it might be eaasier if the template that needed to be filled in were something else, e.g., something plain text based, so that any scripting language could be used with it. The filled out template in e.g., HTML, could them be converted to Word format. Personally, I'd find this easier than trying to script filling in a Word template, since Word doesn't lend itself to scripts interacting with non-Word documents.

Comment: I understand. How would I convert something like HTML into a Word document based on the template?

Comment: Just open it in Word? (Word can import/export HTML files.) Perhaps you could create an HTML template just by exporting a sample document with their template. You'd have to check if everything important was preserved if you converted back. Hard to know without more details.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague as to whether this will be a valid answer or not, but here goes:

To remove formatting from a chunk of text, you can copy it like normal, open the Word document with custom formatting, and use `ctrl` + `shift` + `v` to paste just plain text.