# asciidoc for bachelor thesis?

Tags: documentation

I'm looking for alternatives to LaTeX for documenting my bachelor thesis and I was thinking of asciidoc. I use it for nearly all documentation I write but I'm not sure if it matches the requirements here. Has anyone wrote something like that with asciidoc? Any recommendations?

Comment: Why r'you looking for alternatives to LaTeX?

Comment: This question's reasons do really not need any explanation?? To counter possible flaming, I have written tons of stuff in LaTeX myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plain text markup as a first stage that gets converted into LaTeX and therefore gives you many of the text-formatting benefits of LaTeX. See [Text formatter tools](https://superuser.com/questions/209897/text-formatter-tools/209902#209902)

Have a look at [MutiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) which converts to LaTex from a markup similar to ASCIIDOC. As you probably know, Markdown is used on this website and MultiMarkdown extends that with support for tables etc.

Also see [PanDoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for conversions between many formats.

Comment: +1 Actually I used exactly this setup in the end and was very happy with it.

Comment: @user27076 would you maybe be able to share the sources you created? My wife is about to write her bachelor thesis and I'm looking for better ways for her to write than in Word. She probably could handle markdown, but Latex would definitely be too much. I'd like to see how you handled tables, images and references, thus sources would be perfect!