# Software for exporting resume in different formats

Tags: windows, software-rec, unix, text-editors

I always find myself with the problem of having to translate my resume to different formats for applying for different jobs.

Some people want it in a Word document, RTF, PDF (which is nicer since I use LaTeX for building it), and some others even want it on a text file format.

I was wondering if there is software out there to write the resume and then be able to put the output in different formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools that let you maintain your document as plain text and produce other formats from it.

For example, [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can write

> **plain text**, markdown, reStructuredText, HTML, LaTeX, ConTeXt, **PDF**, **RTF**, DocBook XML, **OpenDocument XML**, ODT, GNU Texinfo, MediaWiki markup, textile, groff man pages, Emacs org-mode, EPUB ebooks, and S5 and Slidy HTML slide shows.

Word 2010 can work with OpenDocument XML as its primary format.

See: [Text formatter tools](https://superuser.com/questions/209897/text-formatter-tools/209902#209902)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Word.

You can export the document as PDF, and copy/paste text, in addition to saving in the native Word format.

If MS Word won't run on your OS (Linux?), you might want to try LibreOffice or OpenOffice, which has similar functionality.

Comment: Yea I am looking for something other than word, but it is a reasonable suggestion

Comment: I would agree--the kicker is that you may need it in .DOC format.  That automatically makes Word probably the best tool for the job, followed by any of its clones

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [groff](http://www.gnu.org/s/groff/) to create CVs in PDF format but switched finally to OpenOffice / LibreOffice because of this issue and had no complaints since then.

I usually offer customers PDF, OpenOffice and Word format, so everybody may pick up his favourite one.