# Keep Latex, PDF and MS-Word in sync

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, latex

My CV is written in Latex using [`moderncv`](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=moderncv&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv&ei=4aa1TpfGBoOxhAeo6dyIBA&usg=AFQjCNFqVrfCt4DKHZi_Ojztdn12Xaa3fA). Whenever I need an updated copy, I convert it to PDF.

Unfortunately, some employers insist on Microsoft Word. This is a real pain, because I lose the beautiful design, and I need to maintain two synchronized versions of the CV.

Any ideas how to automate this?

Comment: A very simple (and probably not useful) solution would be to embed the PDF's pages as images/objects into your word document.

Answer (score 3):

There exist online services and products that claim to convert from LaTeX to MS Word. You could try one of those.

For example: [GrindEQ](http://www.grindeq.com/) or [Tex2Word](http://word2tex.com/) - I have tried neither, the first might just concentrate on equations.

Another approach might be to [generate both LaTeX and Word from a common format](https://superuser.com/questions/209897/text-formatter-tools/209902#209902) - have a look at Pandoc.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you will find a tool that does automatic merging between a Word document and a LaTeX document.

To at least highlight the differences between your two versions you could take two filters that cut away the formatting in both versions and then use the diff-tool to compare the content (i.e., the resulting plain text files). Then you can do the merging by hand.

On *nix it is as simple as this:

```
antiword cv.doc > cv-doc.txt
detex cv.tex > cv-tex.txt
diff -u cv-tex.txt cv-doc.txt
```

(provided you have the antiword package and detex, which would usually come with your tex distribution)

If you want colors in the diff, try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857310/how-to-get-diff-working-like-git-diff).