# A tool for getting HTML Markup Code from rich texts

Tags: microsoft-word, html

Want a dedicated tool For Achieving the below-mentioned result fast

Edit and Work visually to make a styled text or importing from MS-Word or RTF
and get it's markaup HTML(the text with inline coding)

**What I want to get is something similar :**

```
<p class="home">
  <Span style="xxxxx">
    blah blah blah
  </span>
</p>
```

Although it is HTML, but I want just the HTML's source of the text
want to get it with a fast way

Any Tools/Tricks is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Word you can [save as HTML](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826212), which will produce something not entirely unlike your example.

Later versions of Word produce better HTML (early versions produced usable but unreadably repetitive and overcomplicated HTML) so you might want to [clean it up](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=691502)

Some people like to create both HTML and RTF/DOC/DOCX from a [Plain Text Markup](https://superuser.com/q/209897/52492) using something like [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

Comment: Yes I can get the code from a generated HTML,but Isn't there any faster way to generate the text with it's inline HTML code ?

Comment: @Sypress: Maybe I don't understand what you want. Can you update your question with some more detail or a small example? (P.S. see  update to answer ref Pandoc)

Comment: I'll edit the post for more clarify, but before that I'm looking to what included in your answer

Comment: Edited with more clarification, thanks for your participation

Comment: Ok, I'll check them Pandoc seems to do the job but not as I expected , preferably want to do it visually,, and in your other post there are lot's of tools that will take a time to check them , could you suggest me a tool for doing the job I'm looking for

Comment: @Sypress: I think they are all command line tools. Many text editors allow you to configure such external commands and use them from within the text editor (e.g. from menu or toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [**unRTF**](https://www.gnu.org/software/unrtf/).

- **Linux** versions are provided at the above link.
- **Windows** versions are [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unrtf.htm).
- **OS X** lets you install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and `brew install unrtf`.

For example, let's create an RTF document.

[image]

Then convert it to HTML (which is the default setting).

```
unrtf test.rtf
```

This is the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html charset=utf-8>
<!-- Translation from RTF performed by UnRTF, version 0.21.2 -->
<!--font table contains 0 fonts total-->
<!--invalid font number 0-->
</head>
<body><b><font size="3"><font color="#000000">This is a bold text<br>
<br>
<i>This is italics</i><br>
<br>
<u>This is underlined!</u></font></font></b></body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is what I want, but again seems that it's command-line utility, Preferably want to have copy-paste options or possibly could edit it visually

Comment: Well you can just keep both Word (or any RTF editor) and the command line open at the same time. Save the RTF file, run the command.

Comment: Yes I could,  seems no any dedicated tool improved for what I'm looking for,thanks anyway, I'll try it

Comment: Well, you can redirect the output to another file and open it with an HTML editor like Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, TextEdit can edit RTF and save as html. Here is an example of the sort of HTML it spits out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
   <title></title>
   <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
   <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1138.23">
   <style type="text/css">
      p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Helvetica}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="p1">this is a <b>test</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```