# Personal wiki, preferably Python, with Markdown support

Tags: wiki

I'm looking for a wiki package to power a small, private wiki I'm wanting to set up on my home server (Linux). I'd prefer something that is written in Python, but ultimately I need to have Markdown support. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is worth reading: http://superuser.com/questions/209897/text-formatter-tools/209902

Answer (score 5):

[MDWiki](http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki/#!index.md) might meet your needs.

> MDwiki is a CMS/Wiki completely built in HTML5/Javascript and runs 100% on the client. No special software installation or server side processing is required. Just upload the mdwiki.html shipped with MDwiki into the same directory as your markdown files and you are good to go!

It's under active development and seems worth a look.  It doesn't (appear to) have any automatic indexing but other that it's meeting *my* needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you still happy with it? It looks good to me in the first place but I would be grateful for experiences from someone who works with it for some time now. If you changed your mind please tell me which Wiki you are using now. My favorite is MoinMoin for now.

Answer (score 4):

Give a look at [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in) and it's [Markdown Parser](http://moinmo.in/ParserMarket/Markdown).

There's more wiki engines written in Python Wiki: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonWikiEngines

Comment: Thanks. Looking at that page, Markdoc looks like my cup of tea. Unfortunately it's abandoned. Does anyone know if there any viable alternatives (even if they aren't in Python)?

Comment: If you want something simple, there's [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org) with it's [Markdown Plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:markdown), but it's written in PHP