# Modify MS Word document to turn style into text

Tags: microsoft-word

Given an MS Word document, what would be the best way to convert it to a text document and preserve the formatting. So that later we are able to transform the text file back to the MS Word format and retrieve the original formatting.

Comment: save it as [rtf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)?

Comment: Hm.. I rather meant .txt format.

Comment: So that the style is preserved by means of some sort of tags, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how complex the document structure and formatting is, you could use a tool such as [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to [convert an MS Word document to a plain text format](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+word+to+markdown) such as [Markdown-Extra](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/features/).

As you are probably aware, SuperUser questions and answers are written in a subset of Markdown. It is also used in GitHub and other places for documentation. I use it a lot for generating websites (both static and dynamic).

If you have made heavy use of styling then converting the MS Word document to HTML5+CSS3 might preserve more - the tradeoff being much less readable text.

---

Related

- [Text formatter tools](https://superuser.com/q/209897/52492)
- [Lightweight Markup Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language)